# How to overwrite a notebook in GitLab with an updated version?

Tags: gitlab, jupyter

I've successfully copied the most current version of a project from GitLab into my Jupyter notebook using the `git clone` command in the Linux terminal. Let's say the project contains a Python program called python_code.ipynb.

I've already made edits to an earlier version of python_code.ipynb and named it python_code_myversion.ipynb.

Newbie question: How do I overwrite python_code.ipyn with python_code_myversion.ipynb so I can then `git push` my changes back to Gitlab project? I'd prefer to do this rather than manually rewrite my code edits in python_code.ipyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the point of source version control is that you edit the actual files you want to work on, rather than manually creating a copy of them.

In any case, to go back to this workflow to achieve what you are trying to do with your question: it will vary depending on which Operating System you are on. As the `python_code.ipynb` is already under version control, you can essentially delete it and rename the `python_code_myversion.ipynb` to replace it. On Linux, you could do this in one go with this command:

`mv python_code_myversion.ipynb python_code.ipynb`

Comment: Thanks David! Agreed, I should not have made a copy of the Python code. Old habits die hard - I'm used to having v1, v2, etc. of programs + backup copies so this kind of work environment will take some adjustment.